# How to make a list<subset of attributes of table class> = list<ALL attributes of table class> in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, subclass

I have a Java class that was generated by Hibernate that represents a table

Example:

```
public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9144431342277803632L;

    private BigDecimal customerid;
    private String custcompanyname;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String address;

    ... <getters and setters>

}
```

What I would like to do is to make a class that uses a subset of the attributes listed above. For example:

```
public class CustomerShortInfo  {

        private BigDecimal customerid;
        private String firstname;
        private String AddInNewFieldHere; << add in new field that is Not part of Customer

        ... <getters and setters>
}
```

In order to do something like this:

```
List<CustomerShortInfo> = List<Customer>
```

I am trying to keep from making a loop that goes through List in order to do an assignment manually. I have seen that one could do a "subclass" - but - as far as I can tell, this would require something like:

```
public class CustomerShortInfo  extends Customer {

        private BigDecimal customerid;
        private String firstname;

        ... <getters and setters>
}
```

> Again, "Customer" is the class created by Hibernate which adds/removes
>   rows from the table. Each attribute of Customer matches a column in
>   the database table.

Which results in the following:

```
List<CustomerShortInfo> shortcustomerlist;

List< ? extends Customer> longcustomerlist = shortcustomerlist;
```

What is needed is for the assignment to go in the opposite direction. The example below being:

```
List<CustomerShortInfo> = List<Customer>
```

Can this be done? If so, how?

TIA

**Update 2**

Is there any credible way to get th code below working? As of now, I am getting the following:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   ccinfw.main.test.First cannot be cast to ccinfw.main.test.Second  at
>   ccinfw.main.test.TestAssign.main(TestAssign.java:22)

```
public class TestAssign {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         List<First> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
         First firstitem = new First();
         firstList.add(firstitem);

         List<Second> secondList = new ArrayList<>();


         secondList = (List<Second>)(List<?>) firstList;

         System.out.println(" A is " + secondList.get(0).getA()); 
         System.out.println(" B is " + secondList.get(0).getB()); 
         System.out.println(" X is " + secondList.get(0).getX()); 
         System.out.println(" Z is " + secondList.get(0).getZ()); 

    }
}


class Second {

    int b = 3000;
    int a = 4000;
    int z = 5000;
    int x = 9000;

    public int getA() { return a; }
    public int getB() { return b; } 
    public int getZ() { return z; } 
    public int getX() { return x; } 
}


class First  {

    int b = 30;
    int a = 40;
    int c = 10;
    int d = 20;
    int e = 80;
    int f = 90;

    public int getC() { return c; }
    public int getD() { return d; }
    public int getE() { return e; }
    public int getF() { return f; }
    public int getA() { return a; }
    public int getB() { return b; }  

}
```

**Update 1**
The use Sub Classes in this situation will not work for what I am trying to do. When using Sub Classes, all of the attributes of the Super Class `(Customer)` are accessible from the Sub Class `( CustomerShortInfo  )`. The attributes of `CustomerShortInfo` need to stand/used alone. When it was mentioned that A was a Sub Class of B, it was just to describe how the situation.

For example, if Class A had the attributes of:

```
length
height
width
weight
color
manufacturer
```

and Class B had the attributes of
weight 
manufacturer
NumberOfTires

Note that "NumberOfTires" *is not* in the "Super Class"

Then, if the following line was executed:

```
B = copy of (A)
```

then I would just have

```
weight        <<<< values comes from A
manufacturer  <<<< value comes from A
NumberOfTires <<<< Value Not Set from A (since it is not there)
```

> Why would "manufacturer" and "weight" be set when copied from A?
>   Because they have the same attribute name. If I were given a task to "print all the attributes of B".

If I were given a task to print out **ALL** of the attributes of B, I would get:

```
weight, manufacturer, NumberOfTires
```

and not

```
ALL of the attributes of A + NumberOfTires
```

If such a copy is not possible, then one would have to use a number of "getters" and "setters" while looping through a list (in this case Customer) to do the job. This is what I was trying to avoid.

So, any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-supertypes-to-a-list-of-subtypes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you cast a List of supertypes to a List of subtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-supertypes-to-a-list-of-subtypes)

Comment: @araknoid - see Update above. The use of Sub Classes was suggested as a possible solution for the issue I am facing - but unfortunately - this will not work for me. I made an update to the post. If you know of a way to do this, I am all ears (or eyes rather) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get what I needed to do, done, I used Dozer. The links I followed to get things done are below.

```
 *  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358595/how-to-map-collections-in-dozer
 *  http://www.baeldung.com/dozer
 *  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.dozer/dozer/5.5.1
 *  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m68Cq_AnEJU
 *  https://github.com/jiyeonseo/springboot-dozer-sample
```