# How to populate an object with embedded collection from a Map?

Tags: java, collections, pojo, dozer

I am trying to solve this with Dozer and haven't found info on it:

I would like to populate an embedded collection from http request parameters with Dozer.

The request parameters  are available for me as a java.util.Map (as 'requestMap" below) and the entries look like this:

```
Map<String, String> requestMap (key -> value) =
- "id" -> "15"
- "title" -> "Nice article about electric cars"
- "comments[0].text" -> "comment 1"
- "comments[1].text" -> "comment 2"
```

The beans I would like to populate:

```
public class Article {
  int id;
  String title;
  List<Comment> comments;
}

public class Comment {
  String text;
}
```

When I use "mapper.map(requestMap, article)", the article "title" and the "id" attributes get populated from the map nicely. However, the "comments" collection does not get populated.

Is Dozer supposed to be able to populate the collection as well? What do I have to do to get it populated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `Dozer` is smart enough to map this: `comments[0].text` into a `List` of `Comment`.

You can manually extract your values from your`requestMap` and make a list from it.

```
List<Comment> comments = map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().startsWith("comments"))
            .map(entryTwo -> new Comment(entryTwo.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then just include it in your article:

```
article.setComments(comments);
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course Map can have collection. 
When you're using Maps, you can have only two parameters --> `Map<Integer, String>` for instance. 
That's why you need to have a key/id and an object. In this case you can map articles and their IDs.

```
public class Article {
  int id;
  String title;
  List<String> comments; //IMO you don't need class for comments(comment = string)
}
```

`Map<Integer, Article>` where `key == id` in your article.

Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358595/how-to-map-collections-in-dozer)** link about how to map a collection from Dozer

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The Comments entity is more complex in real life, I just tried to slim down the classes for an easy-to-understood question.